# Muse website won't scroll on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, scroll, safari, microsoft-edge

I'm posting on behalf of my SO. Her muse-created website at http://demi.statesideapm.com/ won't scroll horizontally on Chrome, but it works fine on Safari and Edge. The site is just for a uni project and she eventually wants it to be something like this: http://mashup.ikm.gda.pl/

I've found a few people with similar issues but the possible fixes such as removing `position:fixed` and `overflow-x: hidden; height: auto;` don't seem to work. She's trialing some sort of slideshow plugin - could it be to do with that?

Comment: please check console , there is a error of top

Comment: Something about a script being invoked via document.write? I don't know what that means but it's something to Google. I guess it's something to do with Chrome not liking the slideshow plugin I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Page Properties
2. Select Options
3. Browser Scrollbars

Change Vertical from Automatic to Always